# js navbar border bottom line and color change on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a nav bar that changes color based on scroll using js. I want to add a bottom border line prior to scroll with the properties "thin" "solid" and white (#FFFFFF or rbga(255,255,255) but I am having issues with syntax I guess. Everything else works fine, the color change on scroll, but I cannot figure out the bottom border. I'm pretty sure I just have the syntax wrong.

```
type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on("scroll",function(){
    var wn = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(wn > 20){
        $(".navbar").css("background","#191918");       
    }
    else{
        $(".navbar").css("border-bottom","thin solid rbg(255,255,255)");
        $(".navbar").css("background","rgba(0,0,0,0)");     
    }
  });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean prior to scroll? Do you mean it should have those properties by default?

Comment: Correct. The navbar starts with a transparent background with a thin while border at the bottom, upon scrolling the background changes to a dark grey. I tried doing this in css but this js seems to be overriding my css. Maybe I'll try taking out the else statement.

Comment: Continuing with this I also have an issue where the line is not there when the page loads and only works once I scroll. There is currently no css for .navbar and any css added to .navbar does not seem to affect the page. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need use `rgb(255,255,255)`instead of rbga. Rgba requires 4 arguments.
Check difference beetween rgb and rgba https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

You set border-bottom to white color, so I guess, you don't see it. Check example, I hope you see it [here](http://jsbin.com/duherebadu) – Aksana Tolstoguzova 
Regarding background, you set opacity 0, so you can not see it as well, if background of parent also has white color.

Comment: I initially had an opacity of 0.9 in there as well reading rbga(255,255,255,0.9). Either combo does not work - rbga(255,255,255,0.9) or rbg(255,255,255).

Comment: actually, you code looks correct. You set border-bottom, but I guess, you don't see it because it white color. Check example, I hope you see it http://jsbin.com/duherebadu/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: yea, it was a simple syntax error though now I have an issue where the line only show up after I scroll down then back up

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, was a combination of a syntax error and also needed to add a line to the change to transition the line to black as well to cover it.

```
type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on("scroll",function(){
    var wn = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(wn > 20){
        $(".navbar").css("border-bottom","thin solid rgb(0,0,0)");
        $(".navbar").css("background","#191918");
        $(".navbar").css("transition-duration","0.2s");
    }
    else{
        $(".navbar").css("border-bottom","thin solid rgb(255,255,255)");
        $(".navbar").css("background","rgba(0,0,0,0)");     
    }
  });
});
```

Continuing with this I also have an issue where the line is not there when the page loads and only works once I scroll. There is currently no css for .navbar and any css added to .navbar does not seem to affect the page. Any thoughts?